# Jquery display none after opacity 0

Tags: jquery

I have a question regarding Jquery, im trying to throw up a status box which shows a successful save to the end user.

My problem is that after its shown i cant click on any input fields because the div opacity is set to 0 rather than display none, here is my code:

```
function messageBox(x){

n = x.indexOf('SUCCESS');

    if(n!==-1){
        $("#messageBoxSuccess").text(x.replace('SUCCESS', ''))
        $("#messageBoxSuccess").fadeTo(1000, 1);
        $("#messageBoxSuccess").delay(500);
        $("#messageBoxSuccess").fadeTo(1000, 0);

    }else{
        $("#messageBoxError").text(x.replace('ERROR', ''))
        $("#messageBoxError").fadeTo(1000, 1);
        $("#messageBoxError").delay(500);
        $("#messageBoxError").fadeTo(1000, 0);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's fadeTo has a callback event

```
.fadeTo( duration, opacity [, callback] )
```

so you can do

```
$("#messageBoxError").fadeTo(1000, 0, function(){ $(this).hide() });
```

to set display: none at the end of the fadeTo.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
$("#messageBoxSuccess").fadeIn(500, function() { });
$("#messageBoxSuccess").fadeOut(500, function() { });
```

instead. This fades to 0 or 1 and hides (display: none) element after fading to 0 is complete.

Answer (score 0):

`.fadeTo` does not change the display style. If you wish to change the display to none, use `.fadeOut()` and `.fadeIn()`

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, yuou can use `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` to automatically hide/show the contents.  You can also clean up your code a lot like this:

```
function messageBox(x){
    var replaceText, msgBoxId;

    if (x.indexOf('SUCCESS') !== -1) {
        replaceText = "SUCCESS";
        msgBoxId = "#messageBoxSuccess";
    } else {
        replaceText = "ERROR";
        msgBoxId = "#messageBoxError";
    }

    $(msgBoxId).text(x.replace(replaceText, ''))
        .fadeIn(1000).delay(500).fadeOut(1000);
}
```

Changes:

1. Remove the need for the undeclared variable `n` which was an implicit global
2. Set "SUCCESS" or "ERROR" and msg box id in a conditional
3. Move all other common code outside the conditional rather than repeating it twice
4. Use jQuery chaining so that `$("#messageBoxSuccess")` or `$("#messageBoxError") is only evaluate once.
5. Switch to `.fadeOut()` and `.fadeIn()` so content is hidden/shown automatically before/after the animation.